# Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Zoopla'. The duplicate key value is (35268380)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, csv

So After having my question answered on here last time with reference to CSV import, I noticed that because my address data contained comma's it was affecting the amount of columns per row. I've fixed this now however for one entry in the csv it seems to think there is a duplicate ID? Code below:

```
protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Upload and save the file
        string csvPath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(csvPath);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[13] { new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int)),
        new DataColumn("ZooplaURL", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("Branch",typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("HouseNumber",typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("PropAddress",typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("Town",typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("County",typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("Postcode",typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("Price",typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("PropType",typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("Beds",typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("PropStatus",typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("Weeks",typeof(string))  });

        string csvData = File.ReadAllText(csvPath);
        foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\r'))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
            {
                dt.Rows.Add();
                int i = 0;

                foreach (string cell in row.Split(','))
                {
                    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell;
                    i++;
                }
            }


            string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TortoiseDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
            {
                using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                {
                    //Set the database table name
                    sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Zoopla";
                    con.Open();
                    sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My CSV displays as follows:

```
35268380,www.zoopla.com,Fine Country Stamford,12,Bullock Road,Peterborough,,PE7 3TT,1350000,Detached,4,For Sale,37

33333333,www.zoopla.com,Tortoise,7,Tabor Court,Peterborough,,PE7 8GF,180000,Detached,4,For Sale,13
```

It's having a problem with the first entry, trying to submit the ID which is the first entry twice, hence throwing up this error since I'm assigning the ID as the primary key.

Help...

Comment: The error is *very* clear - you tried to enter a record with a key that already exists. This means that there is *already* a record in the database whose ID is 35268380. Did you try to import the same file twice? Did you forget to delete the existing data before importing ?

Comment: This is off a fresh database table. Nothing exists in this table at all. The file was attempted to be imported for the first time.

Comment: There is nothing ambiguous about the message. Either the target table is *not* empty, or the file contains the same key twice. If it's the very first record, the table isn't empty. Are you sure you are using the correct database? The connection string may be targeting a development database that already contains data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your foreach loop is incorrect so it trying to insert same data again, the first foreach loop should close as

```
 foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\r'))
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
        {
            dt.Rows.Add();
            int i = 0;

            foreach (string cell in row.Split(','))
            {
                dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell;
                i++;
            }
        }
  }//loop should be closed here 

        string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TortoiseDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
        {
            using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
            {
                //Set the database table name
                sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Zoopla";
                con.Open();
                sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                con.Close();

            }
        }
    }
```

That is before your connection string initialization.since it is incorrect it performs sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt); many times hence the error.

Comment: Just a small change: You dont need to close the connection explicitly when you are using `using`

Comment: yes, That was a typo while copying and pasting(I used code from the  question). Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: That's solved it! Thank you so much. Been driving me nuts not seeing where this code was wrong. Easy thing to miss I guess when you're staring at it.

Comment: Happens to me all the time :D